# Is there a way to set an option to the value of another option?

Tags: options

For example, I'd like to set

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=tabstop
```

so I can set both values by only changing a single number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `let` command instead.

Like so:

`let &shiftwidth = &tabstop`

The `&` specifies that the variable name is a Vim option. You can also do `:help let-option` to know more about it:

```
:let &{option-name} = {expr1}
        Set option {option-name} to the result of the
        expression {expr1}.  A String or Number value is
        always converted to the type of the option.
        For an option local to a window or buffer the effect
        is just like using the |:set| command: both the local
        value and the global value are changed.
```

Comment: Note that you'll likely want to use `&l:shiftwidth` to only change the buffer local variable.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted since it technically answers my question. I do still have to set both values separately if I wanna change tabstop/shiftwidth values in a running instance of vim.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a better way but you could always do this:

`exec 'set shiftwidth=' . &tabstop`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in this case:

http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27softtabstop%27:

> When 'sts' is negative, the value of 'shiftwidth' is used.

http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shiftwidth%27

> When ['shiftwidth' is] zero the 'ts' value will be used.